# How to write boolean values in Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

Hello i want to write boolean values in a folder like "female" so the name is set to true or false, so i have a list of users belonging to one group i can later read the users from. I don't know how to update the values. Is there a way to do it?

```
const name = reactive({ value: "" });
const gender = reactive({ value1: 'female', value2: 'male' })
    
    function writeUserData1(e) {
      const db = getDatabase();
      set(dbref(db, 'groups/' + gender.value1), {
            name.value = true // true or false || false
      });
    }
```

Using set is bad too, because it updates the whole list as a refresh of all values, deleting perhaps other values unintentionally.. Will it even work, without being authenticated first as user for the visitor? name.value is getting a value coming from a v-model text-input, that gets updated all the time in value. Using name.value before true seems a mistake in Javascript. Also using "true" with quotations therefore does not work. When the name is "Max", it does not get written into firebase as Max = true.

Update: It works when

```
    function writeUserData1(e) {
      const db = getDatabase();
      set(dbref(db, 'groups/' + gender.value1 + "/" + name.value), 
            true
      );
    }
```

But the problem stays the same, with the new values.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are updating a single value?

Instead of { name.value = true } just put true

Whether it works will depend on your project's security settings.

It is not clear what you mean by "folder" though.

Comment: I know, but still the values get overwritten, if the user has not set a first value, of the other users? And the old value if set to true gets not replaced by new updates, but ignored, and stays in the database.